# How did the Falcon end up on Jakku?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

What is the canon explanation for how:

> Han Solo "lost" the Falcon and it ended up on Jakku, abandoned in what looks like a junkyard.

I don't recall the movie discussing this other than in a brief passing.

It seems unlikely that a ship like that would end up sitting derelict on a no-name planet like it did and so I am curious what the canon explanation is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Novelization by Foster covers it. Someone stole it from Han, by the name of Ducain (no info on him yet).

> Impatiently, their captor gestured ever so slightly with the muzzle of his blaster. “Where’d you find this ship?”
>   “Right here.” She saw no reason not to tell the truth. “I mean, down on the surface. Niima Outpost, to be specific.”
>   Dropping his lower jaw to signify his disbelief, he stared back at her. “Jakku? That junkyard?”
>   “Thank you!” Finn said. “Junkyard!” His original opinion confirmed, he shot Rey a look that was pure I-told-you-so.
>   Looking away from them for the first time since they had emerged from below, their captor addressed his towering cohort. “**Told ya we should’ve double-checked the Western Reaches**! Just lucky we were in the general vicinity when the ship powered up and its beacon snapped on.”
>   He turned back to Rey. She was trying to make sense of the mismatched pair standing before her and failing utterly.
>   **“Who had it?” he continued. “Ducain?”**
>   Again, she thought: no reason to prevaricate. “I stole it from a salvage dealer named Unkar Plutt.”
>   Brows narrowed as the weathered visage wrinkled even more. “From who?”
>   “Look.” Taking a chance, Rey lowered her hands so she could spread her arms wide. “I don’t know all the details for sure. I’m not privy to Plutt’s private accounting. But talk says that **Plutt stole this ship from the Irving Boys, who stole it from Ducain**.”
>   **“Who stole it from me!”**

Comment: I think I should read the novels. Or continue feeding you upvotes :-)

Comment: @enderland - accepts and bounties work even better </begging> :)

Comment: @enderland That exact quote is actually in the film, too, or at least one very, very similar to it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - true, but I can't transcribe the whole film, and the script isn't available yet :)

Comment: @DVK Oh, no, I just meant that reading the novel isn't strictly necessary to get that quote. Watching the movie will do it too. :-)